# Knockout Validation Loses Variable Values

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have this Knockout code:

```
var Account = ko.validatedObservable {
ClientID: '',
ConsultantID: '',
AccountNumber: ko.observable(),
Title: ko.observable('Mr'),
Forename: ko.observable(),
Surname: ko.observable().extend({
    required: { message: "* Required" },
    minLength: 2
}),
Submit: function () {

    Account.errors.showAllMessages();

    if (this.isValid())
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/CheckClientDetails",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                Account.ClientID = data.Key;
                alert(Account.ClientID);
                alert(ko.toJSON(Account));
           });
       }
};
```

The first alert shows the Client ID, the JSON from the second alert shows an empty string!

I pass ko.toJSON(Account) to an MVC controller, every property is populated but ClientID is zero.

If I remove the validation (it is from knockout.validation) everything works as expected - but I don't want to lose that functionality!

What do I need to do differently to populate this variable and maintain the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Using the validation turns the Account view model into a method. I changed the code to:

```
Account().ClientID(data.Key);
alert(Account().ClientID());
alert(ko.toJSON(Account()));
```

and it now works.

Comment: I would, but I have to wait 2 days apparently